# Passing values to java program from a command line, how does it work?

Tags: java, command-line, command, command-line-interface

So I always use Eclipse to run my java stuff, I have no clue how to use command prompts. I have an assessment that will be graded by a bot where 2 string parameters will get passed into a function which returns a boolean value.

The bot is going to use a command like "java main.java xyz zyx" to open the file
(assuming xyz and zyx are the strings).

So my question is, to catch those 2 strings, do I have to use 2 variables to catch the 2 string. For example:
string1 = Scanner.nextln(); // This will catch "xyz" into string1??
string2 = Scanner.nextln(); // This will catch "zyx"??

Or does string 1 catch both "xyz zyx" and I have to use a loop to separate them into 2 strings? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: They go in your main's `String[] args`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ...
}
```

Is your program written like this? As in the signature of the main function. The signature holds them as strings in an array. Then you have to process those strings.

Comment: Yeah thats my main

Comment: If the argument is: java program.java A B C. It is space delimited so there 3 arguments in total. You will have an array of [A, B, C] as strings.

Answer (score 1):

Your Main method can be used to catch arguments passed from command line.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(args);
}
```

Comment: Ok so if they enter "java main.java xyz zyx" Does the space in between them make it into 2 seperate arguments or is it only one? So can I do for example string1 = args[0]; I am confused about how to capture it into a variable

Comment: It's only one. It's a string array and you can access array with index. You may try it out by calling the function yourselves